# XmlPullParserException when androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); is called

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

Basically I am using kSoap2 classes for Android. The client app is consuming a web service. If required I can post the code.

I surfed around to figure this out. I get following error message
expected: START_TAG{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/envelope/}Envelope(posiiton:START_TAG@1:6 in java.io.InputStreamReader@437b40f0) when androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); is called.

What I gathered so far is "The xml is not parsed correctly or there was no response from the webservice server." Any suggestions?

Also, When I tried other external webservice: http://www.deeptraining.com/webservices/GetWeather, I received: IOException on androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

IOException message: Host is unresolved, any idea how to solve this, here I didn't get the XmlPullParserException (may be it will show up once this is fixed).

Thanks and I appreciate your insight and time.

Anjana.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and i resolved it. I only wrote a wrong URL.
I have a php web service using NUSOAP.

Wrong address:
private static final String URL = "http://www.mywebsite.com/service/myservice.php?wsld";

Right address:
private static final String URL = "http://www.mywebsite.com/service/myservice.php";

I advise you to check the parameters you are passing to ksoap2, because it works fine.

Bye bye.